# JQuery search function to show a hidden result on same page

Tags: jquery, function, search, anchor

I am currently trying to create a search function that will select a specific div from the search result and toggle it from hidden.

This is the code I have so far;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="../jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>   
<script>
function SearchBarFunction() {
document.getElementById("SearchBarDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

}  */ This will hide the container holding the answer/*
$(document).ready (function(){
$("#LTT-Area").hide()
}); 
             */ This is the search function */
function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a;
input = document.getElementById("SearchBarInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("SearchBarDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  a[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  a[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  } 
 }


             */ This is the work in-progress code to show the value */
var txt = $('#SearchBarDropdown').val();
 $('SearchBarInput').each(function(){
   if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) !=-1){
     $(this).show();
   }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main_answer">           
  <button onclick="SearchBarFunction()" class="dropbtn">Search</button>
    <div id="SearchBarDropdown" class="dropdown-content">   
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="SearchBarInput" 
       onkeyup="filterFunction()">

     <a href="#answer1">Why doesnt this work?</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="LTT-Area">
  <div id="answer1"><h2>Why doesnt this work?</h2><a>This doesn't work 
 because it is broken</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using an anchor to locate the answer on the page however I have the answers set as hidden on doc ready. What I am having trouble is creating a search function which will show the hidden answers in-order for the anchor to then locate afterward.

Thank you for taking the time to check this out.